# how can i use django session in GAE

Tags: django, session, app-engine-patch

i have an app in GAE, but i have no idea about how to use django session, although i know the app-engine-patch may be helpful. who can give me a demo how to use it for session? thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You should try django-nonrel http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/django-nonrel